# Core Data find item sort order index with sort parameters

Tags: macos, core-data

I have fetched an array of items from my core data store sorted by a "Name" property. The user of my app is able to change the name of the item, and the UI is supposed to update to show the results sorted in the new way with a cool animation. The only trouble I'm having is retrieving the new order index of the item after its name is updated. Is it inefficient for me to just fetch the whole result set again (could be quite large... 1000+ records) for the sole purpose of finding the objects new sort order index?

Can anyone think of a better way of accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not inefficient it is the way it is supposed to work. If you have very large fetches you can make the fetches more efficient by restricting the fetch batch size, explicitly fetching as faults, fetching by attribute etc.

See the [Core Data Programming Guide:Performance](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW1) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that's helpful